# What REG-BINARY to set for FailureAction for service

Tags: c#, service, recovery

I have a service for which I want to set Data value for FailureAction in registry. Currently there is value set in registry. Value is set using RegKey.SetValue("FailureActions", Value);

**I would like to know:**

1) How these bytes of Value correspond to recovery option of service (like how to find out particular sequence in registry means setting 'First failure' as 'Restart the Service')

2) Also I need to change in registry FailureAction which will correspond to 'Subsequent failures' as 'Restart the Service'

**Here is my finding using trial and error method:**

a)Manually change setting of recovery for service then registry entry changes. Copy that value and use in code. It set 'Subsequent failures'

b)Change original value in code. It set 'Subsequent failures'

But value from a) and b) does not match but I see same result if I right click on service and see recovery option. To understand this I would like to know answers to question 1) and 2).

Appreciate your comment\clue.

Answer (score 24):

To explain the meaning of bytes in data value of FailureActions registry key, I will take this example:

[image]

The bytes in this representation correspond to this structure:

```
typedef struct _SERVICE_FAILURE_ACTIONS {
    DWORD     dwResetPeriod;
    LPTSTR    lpRebootMsg;
    LPTSTR    lpCommand;
    DWORD     cActions;
    SC_ACTION *lpsaActions;
} SERVICE_FAILURE_ACTIONS, *LPSERVICE_FAILURE_ACTIONS;
```

The first four bytes `80 51 01 00` are the value of `dwResetPeriod` structure's member. It is the time after which to reset the failure count to zero if there are no failures. It is counted in seconds. In this example the reset period is 0x15180 sec (because of little endian). In decimal it is equivalent of 86400 sec or equal to 24 hours. So, if in a period of 24 hours there are no failures then the failure count is reset to zero.

The next four bytes `00 00 00 00` correspond to `lpRebootMsg`. More info about this structure's member and the next one can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/windows/desktop/ms685939(v=vs.85).aspx)

The next four bytes `00 00 00 00` correspond to `lpCommand`.

The next four bytes `03 00 00 00` correspond to `cActions`. This member is the number of elements in the `lpsaActions` array. In this case we have 3 elements.

The next four bytes `14 00 00 00` correspond to `lpsaActions` which is a pointer to an array of type `SA_ACTION`.

Finally,  `01 00 00 00 60 EA 00 00
       01 00 00 00 60 EA 00 00
       00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00` is the content of an array of type `SC_ACTION` pointed by `lpsaActions`. We have 3 instances of this structure corresponding to the 3 lines of bytes. The structure `SC_ACTION` is declared below:

```
typedef struct _SC_ACTION {
    SC_ACTION_TYPE Type;
    DWORD          Delay;
} SC_ACTION, *LPSC_ACTION;
```

More info about `SC_ACTION` and `SC_ACTION_TYPE` can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/windows/desktop/ms685126(v=vs.85).aspx).

So, first line `01 00 00 00 60 EA 00 00` means: : "In case of a failure, restart the service (`01 00 00 00`) after 60 sec (`60 EA 00 00` == to 0xEA60 ms == 60000 ms == 60 sec)." The second line means the same. The third line means "In case of failure, take no action(`00 00 00 00`) after 0 sec (`00 00 00 00`)"

How this works? Each time a service fails, the service controller increments a failure count `N` and take the action `N-1` specified in the array pointed by `lpsaActions`. In our case, first time the service fails, `N` is incremented to 1 and the controller will execute the actions indexed by `0` which means, restart the service after 60 sec. Second time it fails the `N` is incremented to 2 and the action `N-1 = 1` is taken which means, restart the service after 60 sec. The third time the service fails the controller executes the last action in array which in our case is, take no action. If `N` is greater than `cActions`, the service controller repeats the last action in the array. In this case the service is no started anymore.

Comment: @Magg this is a great answer, you should mark it as such!

Comment: Detailed answer. Appreciate it

Comment: I'm seeing registry entries that have an SA_ACTION array count greater than 3. One service has 6 elements, another has 4. Any idea what that could mean?